# javax.swing.UIManager.getIcon(Object key) returns null when String-keys are streamed from an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, icons, uimanager

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to visualize some `javax.swing.Icon`s from the `javax.swing.UIManager`. On the internet I've found a list of `UIManager`-keys, which will not only return `Icons` but also `Strings`, `Colors` and so on. So in this step I want to filter the list of keys so only the `Icon`-keys remain.

**My Approach:**
I copied a list of `UIManager` keys into a textfile and included it as recource in my Java-Project. I successfully read the file so I split the file-content by lines and added them to an `ArrayList` of `Strings`. Now i wanted to stream the content of this `ArrayList` and filter the keys by wether the `UIManager.getIcon(Object key)`-Method returns `null` or not...

**My Problem**
so far: the `UIManager` always returns `null`. I printed all the keys and the `UIManager` result to the console (*see "Output / Test - stream keys" in my code*). If i manually copy a key from the console (one that I know should work) and paste it into the exact same piece of code, it actually works (*see "Output / Test - single Key" in my code*).

**Interesting Behavior** shows when I append a `String` to the key that I want to print to the console (*See the variable "suffix" under "Output / Test - stream Keys" in my code*). If the variable `suffix` does not start with "\n", the following print-Method in the stream will only print the `suffix` and no longer show the other content. For example if I type `String suffix = "test";` only "test" will be printed from the `.forEach(key->System.out.println(... + key + suffix);` However, this behavior does not show up in the "Output / Test - single Key"-Example.

I have no idea, what is going on or if the (in my opinion) strange behavior as anything to do with the problem. I appreciate any kind of help!

**Piece from "UIManagerKeys.txt":**
Here are some keys for testing and reproducibility purposes...

```
FileView.computerIcon
FileView.directoryIcon
FileView.fileIcon
FileView.floppyDriveIcon
FileView.hardDriveIcon
FormattedTextField.background
FormattedTextField.border
windowText
```

**My Code:**

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> uiKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "recources/UIManagerKeys.txt";
        ClassLoader classLoader = new Main().getClass().getClassLoader();

        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

        // Check: is File found?
        System.out.println("File Found : " + file.exists());

        try {
            // Read File Content
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

            // Split by line and collect
            String[] keys = content.split("\n");
            uiKeys.addAll(Arrays.asList(keys));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        // Output / Test - stream Keys
        System.out.println("Total Number of Keys: " + uiKeys.size());
        String suffix = ""; // Interesting behavior when String is not empty
        uiKeys.stream()
                .map(key -> key.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\n", "")) // Just to be sure
                .forEach(key -> System.out.println("IconFound: " + (UIManager.getIcon(key) != null) + "\tKey: " + key + suffix));

        // Output / Test - single Key
        System.out.println("\n");
        String key = "FileView.directoryIcon"; // Copied from console
        System.out.println("IconFound: " + (UIManager.getIcon(key) != null) + "\tKey: " + key + suffix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to visualize some javax.swing.Icons from the javax.swing.UIManager.
>
> I copied a list of UIManager keys into a textfile

There is no need to create the text file. You just get all the properties from the UIManager and check if the Object is an Icon:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();

    for ( Enumeration enumm = defaults.keys(); enumm.hasMoreElements(); )
    {
        Object key = enumm.nextElement();
        Object value = defaults.get( key );

        if (value instanceof Icon)
            System.out.println( key );
    }
}
```

> On the internet I've found a list of UIManager-keys,

Check out: [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for a little graphical tool that displays all the properties.

Your approach of reading the files seems a little complicated. Here is a simple approach to reading the lines of a file into a ListArray:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "ReadFile.java" ) );
        String line;

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        in.close();

        System.out.println(lines.size() + " lines read");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Your approach does pretty much everything I need. (However, I am still confused why my approach doesn't work).

Adressing your file-reading point: My approach is the easiest to read files from recources, i guess. To the best of my knowledge the FileReader doesn't work anymore once the project is compiled and used as library or standalone tool; but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: *I am still confused why my approach doesn't work)* - I have never used streams, so I don't know what is wrong with the code. But your approach has many more steps than what I suggested. So if one step is wrong the whole approach is wrong. That is why you should simplify the steps. *FileReader doesn't work anymore once the project is compiled and used as library or standalone tool* - Once you have access to a `File` object the `FileReader` will work.